# Failing to Upload Large JSON file to Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a 1GB json file to upload to Firebase RTDB but when I press Import, it's loading for a while and then I get this Error:

There was a problem contacting the server. Try uploading your file again.

I have tried to upload a 30mb file and everything is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your file it too big to upload to Firebase in one go. There are no parameters to tweak here, and you'll have to use another means of getting the data into the database.

You might want to give the [Firebase-Import](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import) library ago, the [Firebase CLI's `database:set` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands), or write your own import for your file format using the Firebase API.

Comment: The library has a limit of approx 400mb databases. The lack of this feature is problematic for keeping Firebase projects synced (eg when you have multi environment)